# umake - no visual studio code launcher icon

Tags: unity, launcher, mint

I just installed a fresh version of linux mint and want to get visual studio code working.

so I installed umake, and then ran

```
sudo umake web visual-studio-code
```

I accepted the default install folder (.local/share/umake/web/visual-studio-code), and accepted the licence and term aggreement.

Then installer then downloaded the files and output

```
Installation done
```

However, it did not create a launcher icon like it was supposed to. I can navigate to the folder, but can't find an executable.

So how do I run the editor?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't install with sudo. ubuntu-make installs software in your own home directory by default (~/.local/share/umake/...).

```
umake ide visual-studio-code
```

I got here by also finding out, there is no launcher generated. The binary is located in the base installation directory and can be opened with:

```
~/.local/share/umake/ide/visual-studio-code/code
```

So until they fix it, we have to create it manually using any menu-editor (menulibre, alacarte, ...) or creating the .desktop file yourself. Place the file as `~/.local/share/applications/visual-studio-code.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Visual Studio Code
Icon=/home/dionysius/.local/share/umake/ide/visual-studio-code/resources/app/resources/linux/code.png
Exec="/home/dionysius/.local/share/umake/ide/visual-studio-code/code" %f
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
```

**EHEM!** Use your home directory instead of `/home/dionysius`

Comment: If you get an error about needing libgconf-2-4 when running code, then just run "sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4" (swapping out 2-4 for the required version if that changes). This is a dependency of electron.